# How to track conversion funnels across multiple domains with Google Analytics, getClicky, and CloudFlare

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, dns-servers, cloudflare, conversions

What we need: We need to implement funnel and conversion tracking across multiple domains. Currently, we have funnels that start in one domain but end in another domain. We have full control and access across all domains. We want to track the funnel from start to finish and identify the weak points in the funnel to improve sales conversions.

What we have planned: Using a mixture of Google Analytics and getClicky with CloudFlare. We want to use CloudFlare to force the pixels and tracking codes for both getClicky and CloudFlare onto every page across every domain.

Concerns: How will this affect Google Analytics reports? Will this likely make it difficult to track and see how each funnel operated independently? Is CloudFlare capable of handling this? The last thing we want to do is have to micro-manage UA tracking code across 6 different sites trying to make sure the conversion tracking doesn't break.

If anyone has experience tracking conversions across multiple platforms, your input on this would be great. Are we headed in a good direction here? Are we way out in left field or have we missed the ballpark completely?

Answer (score 1):

Below is normal snippet

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'example1.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Below is multi-domain GA snippet

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['example2.com'] );
```

This links example1.com and example2.com together.

Source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en#GA